# .trigger('chosen:updated') does not work... Chosen v1.6.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

So I have this in my cshtml...

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.RoleHelper.roleIDs, ViewBag.Roles as MultiSelectList, new { @id = "roles", @name="roles", @class = "chosen-select", data_placeholder = "Select Role..." })
```

I have activated chosen by using this:

```
<script>    $(".chosen-select").chosen({ width: "100%", display_selected_options: false });</script>
```

Then I have a button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="selAll()" id="select_all" name="select_all" value="Select All">
```

Which calls this function:

```
<script>
function selAll()
{
    $('#roles option').prop('selected', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
    alert("test");
}</script>
```

Basically what I want to do is when the button is clicked, all the roles in my roles multiselect box is selected. Problem is, my chosen-enabled multi select box does not reflect this change. I can see that all the options are selected, but chosen does not update. (By updated I mean, the options are not shown)

Chosen is also not updated when I tried to dynamically populate the options of one of my multi select boxes. This is after I called .trigger('chosen:updated').

Can anyone please tell me what I did wrong? And how to solve this...

BTW: The alert works meaning that $('#roles option').prop('selected', true).trigger('chosen:updated'); is called successfully...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to trigger the `chosen:updated` on the wrong element.  Try using `$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated")` after you select the option and see if that works.

Comment: I did this.... $('#roles option').prop('selected', true);
        $('.chosen-select').trigger("chosen:select"); But still doesn't work...

Comment: Can you try adding your rendered HTML or better yet create a jsfiddle?

Comment: Oh, and also, used "chosen:updated", not "chosen:select"

Comment: Ooops... sorry about that...yeah I used chosen:updated... Still not good... I cant include the whole rendered html cause its too long... Ill just paste here some of the options in the select....  select class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Role..." id="roles" multiple="multiple" name="RoleHelper.roleIDs"><option value="1">Abnormality Monitor</option>
<option value="2">Area Supervisor</option>
...</select>. I've read many questions and answers here and all i see is just trigger the chosen:updated but nothing happens on my side....